# php contact form alert is not showing

Tags: php, html

After submitting the contact form it should display "Thank You" but it doesn't display it. And when we don't type the input type the error doesn't show. My website is alzirabarretto.com/webdesigner

```html
<!-- PHP CONTACT FORM -->
    
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'Portfolio Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'alzirabarretto@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'My Feedback ';
        
        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
 
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }
        
        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }
        
        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        
        // If there are no errors, send the email
        if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage ) {
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
            } else {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>



<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
                 
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
        </div>
    </div>
                        
                
    <div class="row control-group">
         <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
             <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
        </div>
    </div>
                        
    <div class="row control-group">
         <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Subject</label>
                <input type="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" id="sub">
             <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
         </div>
    </div>
                        
    <div class="row control-group">
         <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Message</label>
                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
             <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
         </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="submit">Send</button>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <?php echo $result; ?>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Rahautos it supposed to be '</form>' and not '<form/>' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$result is out of scope when it is printed. Try defining it in start.

```
    $result="";
```

Add the following code where you want to print it.

```
      if($result!="")
      {
         echo $result;
      }
```

Comment: Try declaring it before if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {